Can the Maven Enforcer Plugin include optional transitive dependencies in its 'one version' checker rules?
The current maven project I am currently working with is a integration-type project. It includes an extensive list of dependencies. These dependencies often carry a wide range of dependencies of their own. With this, we utilize the Maven Enforcer Plugin to check its full dependency graph, and enforce the dependencyConvergence Rule https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html. This way, the transitive dependencies of direct dependencies always resolve to a single version to avoid conflicts in interfaces or runtimes.
We encountered a situation where the enforcer did not trigger on an optional transitive dependency.
Consider the following project structure:
proj_b <-- proj_d v1.0
proj_c <-- proj_d v1.1

proj_a <-- proj_b + proj_c

This will cause the Enforcer plugin to give an error noting that proj_d is included as a dependency for v1.0 and v1.1, which is what we want.
But, if proj_c declares its dependency as optional, the Enforcer Plugin does not throw an error.
The pom.xml for proj_c would be looking like this:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>proj_d</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
       <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Is there a way to configure the Enforcer plugin to also include the transitive optional dependencies?
I tested this with:
Maven 3.9.8
Maven Enforcer Plugin 3.5.0
I tried looking into the source code of the enforcer plugin to see any way to include optional transitive dependencies, but to no avail.
Is it even an issue of the enforcer plugin? is it the maven dependency resolver that does not expose optional transitive dependencies?

From my knowledge it will not take into account the optional deps at all... which are defined as optional...

@khmarbaise In your expertise, considering the dependency mechanism in Maven, do you think this a bug/a feature request/out of scope?
